# Как узнать, каким процессом занят файл?

Tags: c#, файлы

Приветствую. 
Собственно интересует такой вопрос: "Как узнать, каким процессом занят файл?"
Можно ли это реализовать посредством **FileSystemWatcher** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263609/1463665) предлагают воспользоваться утилитой [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) и убить процесс таким образом:

```
string fileName = @"c:\aaa.doc"; //Путь к занятому файлу

Process tool = new Process();
tool.StartInfo.FileName = "handle.exe";
tool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName+" /accepteula";
tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
tool.Start();           
tool.WaitForExit();
string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern))
{
    Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).Kill();
}
```

Но ещё есть гипервариант: [листинг на PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/VuhVnRC1), который тоже покажет процесс, который занял файл.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз был нужен вариант без посторонних программ)